# Problems attaching two sqlite databases with https://cocoapods.org/pods/SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, database, sqlite, execute, sqlite.swift

I am using [stephencelis/SQLite.swift](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SQLite.swift) and try to attach 2 databases at runtime:

ATTACH DATABASE \'(databasePath.Local)\' AS LOCAL_USER_DB;

```
//
//  DatabaseWrapper.swift
// ...
//

import UIKit
import SQLite

class DatabaseWrapper {

    // MARK: - Constants

    struct databaseName {
        static let Interface: String = "app_interface_sqlite3_db.db3"
        static let Local: String = "app_local_sqlite3_db_local.db3"
    }
    struct databasePath {
        static let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true
        ).first!
        static let Interface = "\(path)/\(databaseName.Interface)"
        static let Local = "\(path)//\(databaseName.Local)"
        static let Interface_Bundle: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "app_interface_sqlite3_db", ofType: "db3") ?? ""
        static let Local_Bundle: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "app_local_sqlite3_db_local", ofType: "db3") ?? ""
    }

    // MARK: Copy Databases

    public static func copyDatabasesIfNeeded() {
        copyDatabaseIfNeeded(databaseName: databaseName.Interface)
        copyDatabaseIfNeeded(databaseName: databaseName.Local)
    }

    public static func copyDatabaseIfNeeded(databaseName: String) {

        print("PATH: \(databasePath.Interface)")

        // Move database file from bundle to documents folder
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                            in: .userDomainMask)

        guard documentsUrl.count != 0 else {
            return // Could not find documents URL
        }

        let finalDatabaseURL = documentsUrl.first!.appendingPathComponent(databaseName)

        if !( (try? finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false) {
            print("DB does not exist in documents folder")

            let documentsURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent(databaseName)

            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: (documentsURL?.path)!, toPath: finalDatabaseURL.path)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Couldn't copy file to final location! Error:\(error.description)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Database file found at path: \(finalDatabaseURL.path)")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Attach Local User Database TESTS
    public static func attachDatabase() {

        do {
            // if the database connection works

            let db = try Connection(databasePath.Interface);

            let attachStr = "ATTACH DATABASE \'\(databasePath.Local)\' AS LOCAL_USER_DB;"

            try db.execute(attachStr)

        } catch {
            // handle error
            print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
        }

    }

    public static func checkIfDatabase2IsAttached() -> Bool {

        var isAllreadyAttached = false

        do {
            // if the database connection works

            let db = try Connection(databasePath.Interface);

            // seq, name, file
            var row_counter = 0
            for row in try db.prepare("PRAGMA database_list;") {
                print("\n\n----------\row: \(row)\n----------\n\n")
                row_counter += 1
            }
            isAllreadyAttached = (row_counter == 2) ? true : false

        } catch {
            // handle error
            print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
        }

        return isAllreadyAttached
    }

    public static func testIfDatabaseWasAttached() {

        do {
            // if the database connection works

            let db = try Connection(databasePath.Interface);

            for row in try db.prepare("SELECT * FROM LOCAL_USER_DB.users;") {
                print("row: \(row)")
            }

        } catch {
            // handle error
            print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
        }

    }

    // ...

}
```

When I call

```
// Copy both databases if needed
        DatabaseWrapper.copyDatabasesIfNeeded()
        DatabaseWrapper.attachDatabase()

        if (DatabaseWrapper.checkIfDatabase2IsAttached()) {
            print("ATTACHED")
        } else {
            print("NOT ATTACHED YET")
        }

        DatabaseWrapper.testIfDatabaseWasAttached()
```

Unfortunately I doesn't work and I do not get any error messages.

In the consule I get the Log:

> ### ---------- ow: [Optional(0), Optional("main"), Optional("..../Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F93B5F0C-87D0-439C-ACB9-B1C6B5B7BE60/data/Containers/Data/Application/BB9587A1-2512-4003-ABC0-8AB1A7F6B4AF/Documents/app_interface_sqlite3_db.db3")]
>
> NOT ATTACHED YET Unexpected error: no such table:
>   LOCAL_USER_DB.users (code: 1).

Has anyone a clue, has done this before or anyone help me?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Maybe this helps for those having this same issue. It's a temporary "solution" (next step):**

Found out:
It's on the planing list but not implemented yet. It's good to know but it's a pitty. Since Stephen Celis project since to be the be the best sqlite one for Swift.

Solutions are:

1. Contribute to the project. See discussion: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/30
2. Write your own wrapper. For here [Attach two SQLite-DB files to query over both files in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440681/attach-two-sqlite-db-files-to-query-over-both-files-in-swift) discribed solution worked. For further inspiration see also: [Accessing an SQLite Database in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift)

For getting my project to run: first I go for 2. If it works I plan to post it for the inspiration of 1.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the issue related to `testIfDatabaseWasAttached()`. Are you sure that your table has name `LOCAL_USER_DB.users`? You can use this code - I've checked and get users from table `LOCAL_USER_DB.users` (the table has a strange name but ok).

```
public static func testIfDatabaseWasAttached() {
    do {

        let db = try Connection(databasePath.Interface);
        for element in try db.prepare(Table("LOCAL_USER_DB.users")) {
            print(element)
        }
    } catch {
        // handle error
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
}
```

you should be sure that you have table with name `LOCAL_USER_DB.users` and error says about your issue. This struct of db:
[image]

PS when I run your code - 2 databases are created in `[.documents]`, but they are completely empty (no data at all, there are two db only). I recommend check logic of flow

Comment: @CGN I guess that, first of all, the issue with naming and understanding the data structure in the database (tables and their contents)

Comment: Thanks for your good input. I tried your function and I get the following error: Unexpected error: no such table: LOCAL_USER_DB.users (code: 1). The "ATTACH DATABASE \'\(databasePath.Local)\' AS LOCAL_USER_DB;" seems not to be working. It works when I run it in my sqlite client ("DB Browser for SQLite") but not with the SQLite.swift Library. I want attach the second database to the first at run time. Thats my issue.

Comment: @CGN I work a lot with SQLite.swift Library on huge projects and frankly, it performs all the standard functionality, if you understand what is required of the library. In your case, there is a naming problem and native queries.

Comment: @Nikoleav: Sure, but my issue is in technically attach to sqlite databases at run time. The tables structure and content could be any. My collegue how did the Android app had no issue in attaching to databases at runtime using the same statement. I wonder why should not be possible. Maybe I have to use a different SQLite Library than SQLite.swift or some old Objective C Code? It just hast to go. If the attaching would work, the checkIfDatabase2IsAttached() would return a true.